# The proxy server is refusing connections vs Access Denied

Tags: networking, proxy

Our Network administrators configured Proxy server to block one website[LinkedIn.com]. On directly accessing http://www.linkedin.com/, seeing error message - "Access Denied". But when I accessed LinkedIn site as "https://in.linkedin.com/", getting error - "The proxy server is refusing connections". Can someone please tell me the difference between this errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is most likely in your browser's configuration for proxy servers.

`http://linkedin.com/ -> regular http
https://linkedin.com/ -> SSL encrypted http`

I suspect you have different servers or possibly just different ports configured for SSL and for regular http. Normally, you can configure just one that is used for all connection types. Either way, your network administrators should be able to resolve the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible that the proxy is responsible for both. When denying a request for an HTTPS site it is hard for a web filter to give a "sensible" error message, as you're not able to do much to the HTTPS stream without a "Man in the middle" type scenario.

It's for this reason some web filters (including Smoothwall, my employer) when blocking a https request will MiTM resulting in the user getting a certificate error, but once they click through, a full "blockpage" which gives a reason (You can't go on linkedin because your admin has set policy as such), rather than the more brutal option of simply dropping the connection and letting the web browser pick up the bits.

It is also, of course, possible that your proxy server is misconfigured for HTTPS as @Etherfish suggests: you can test this by seeing if an "allowed" https site works ok (try salesforce or an online bank).